# Trying to calculate Strahler orders but all values over 5 just give me a map where all values are 0

Tags: qgis

I'm a complete beginner in using GIS.

I need to calculate the Strahler orders of an area, but all values above 5 calculated give me a blank map. I checked the saved document and I can tell that there are actual colored lines(?) on it. This is practical work for a class. The process was basically merging 4 DEM tiles, reprojecting them from 4326 to 32632, clipping a subset DEM to ease calculations, filling sinks with the Wang & Liu algorithm, and using that DEM to calculate the Strahler orders.

PS: when using the algorithms, I had to save them as SDAT files since they wouldn't be projected if saved as .tif

I'm using Qgis 2.18.11

[image]

Comment: So the tiff contains pixels with different values, but in QGIS it is rendered all black. You may have to adjust the range of values to be displayed, like in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280271/different-dem-range-values-in-qgis-and-arcgis/280276#280276)

Comment: PS: QGIS 2.8 is fairly old, many functions have been improved since then

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to apply what you said but it didn't have any effect. I'll lrobably try a newer version of QGIS and see if the problem stays.